# RMAN-06172: no AUTOBACKUP found or specified handle is not a valid copy or piece

Tags: oracle, rman

I'm trying to restore an spfile as the first step in a cloning procedure from a Simpana backup of a 12c DB (TEST44) to it's duplicate (TEST15). The Source DB has been successfully backed up using Simpana. Autobackup has been set:

```
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
```

I can list the backup set that the restore is using:

```
    BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
30      Full    128.50M    SBT_TAPE    00:00:04     18-JUN-18
        `BP Key: 30   Status`: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20180618T164547
        Handle: c-958109427-20180618-03   Media: V_453862_1340469
  SPFILE Included: Modification time: 18-JUN-18
  SPFILE db_unique_name: TEST44
  Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 975546       Ckp time: 18-JUN-18
```

The target DB is mounted. I need to restore the spfile before I can restore the controlfiles but I'm hitting the following error:

```
RMAN> 2> 3> 4> 5> 6> 7> 8> 9> 10> 11> 12> 13> 14> 15> 16> 
executing command: SET DBID
database name is "TEST44" and DBID is 958109427

allocated channel: a1
channel a1: SID=254 device type=SBT_TAPE
channel a1: CommVault Systems for Oracle: Version 10.0.0(BUILD116)

allocated channel: a2
channel a2: SID=317 device type=SBT_TAPE
channel a2: CommVault Systems for Oracle: Version 10.0.0(BUILD116)

allocated channel: a3
channel a3: SID=380 device type=SBT_TAPE
channel a3: CommVault Systems for Oracle: Version 10.0.0(BUILD116)

allocated channel: a4
channel a4: SID=442 device type=SBT_TAPE
channel a4: CommVault Systems for Oracle: Version 10.0.0(BUILD116)

Starting restore at 18-JUN-18

channel a1: no AUTOBACKUP in 7 days found
channel a2: no AUTOBACKUP in 7 days found
channel a3: no AUTOBACKUP in 7 days found
channel a4: no AUTOBACKUP in 7 days found
released channel: a1
released channel: a2
released channel: a3
released channel: a4
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 06/18/2018 17:48:39
RMAN-06172: no AUTOBACKUP found or specified handle is not a valid copy or piece

RMAN> 

Recovery Manager complete.


Running: restore spfile to '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbs/spfileTEST15.ora' from 'c-958109427-20180618-03
```

Any pointers on what I should be looking at in order to resolve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was the result of an incorrectly configured Commvault client installation on the target host. Using the Commcell GUI it was possible to see the host was not in a usable state. A full de-install and re-install of the CV client fixed the issue.